# Parsing an XML response using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using PHP to parse an XML response,

After some debugging, I have found a strange occurrence with my application. This is what I've been doing, I make the request and then I echo the entire response. The response is as-expected XML. When I copy this entire document and paste it into a php script which then runs simplexml_load_string on it, it spits out a Simple XML object like you would expect.

When I run it from the actual request, I print the response, I can see it, looks like normal XML. But then when I load the xml string using simplexml_load_string, it prints nothing at all. I have tried a few variations but every object it returns is just empty. The script is running because I echo "Done" at the end of the script. I have tried each of these:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars_decode($response_body));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response_body);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response_body);
```

The first one I've tried (with htmlspecialchars_decode) is because, for some reason, the unedited response, prints with `&lt;` signs instead of '<' signs. Any suggestions, or advice would be hugely helpful!

By the way, I am printing the object like this:

```
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead:

```
var_dump($xml);
```

It will show you what type the variable is. This way you will know if the variable is `false` or `null`, which `print_r` does not. If the variable is `null` or `false` it won't print anything.

So, If you get an `SimpleXML` object all is fine, if you however get `false` then the parsing encountered an error. To being able to figure out what went wrong you need to turn on `E_WARNING`, since `simplexml_load_string` produces a warning and not a error.

[Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [asXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) function.

> SimpleXMLElement::asXML — Return a well-formed XML string based on SimpleXML element

### EDIT

You mentioned below that the object is returning empty from the pieces of code posted in the question. Have you tried var_dump? I suspect that you're actually getting the return of 'FALSE'. That will print out as nothing and it happens when you have malformed XML and you try to pass it through the code in your question.

Here are a couple of steps you can try:

- Hit ctrl+u in your browser -- I'll bet that you've a `&tl;` where you really want a `<`. Either that or you have an `&quot;` when you want `"`. CTRL-U should show you that.
- Copy the output from the browser into a local file and see what simplexml_load_file says about it. It could be that you're missing a closing tag or something.

Comment: Well thank you for the response, but I am unable to convert the XML response into a SimpleXML element. The object that the xml is converted to is empty when I print_r it

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your xml object into array and then use like an array.

**Example :**

```
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/xml');

        function toarray($data) {
        if (is_object($data)) $data = get_object_vars($data);
        return (is_array($data)) ? array_map(__FUNCTION__,$data) : $data;
        }

        $dat = toarray($xml);
```

Now `$dat` becomes array and use it like

```
echo $dat['key_name'];
```

Hope it may help to get your result. 
Thank You
CHeers...!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it's not printing with 'echo', is that `echo` prints a variable.

The simplexml_load_string is a built in function that turns an output of an XML function into an object.

You can not use `echo` to print an object.  `print_r()` is a better option to print objects.

Comment: `print_r` is not, however, a good option to print SimpleXML objects, as it doesn't show the full structure. See http://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug